# Spring getCurrentSession() and save sevaral object

Tags: spring, transactional

Currently, I use openSession(), begin and commit transaction in a method with classic dao and service layers and save/update/delete multiple object in it. If any error exist I am sure that any save/update in this method did not done.

Is it possible to save more than one object in a method called with @Transactional annotation via getCurrentSession() and it is safe if this guarantee that all object in this method saved/updated or any did not done? And if possible how can I use rollback in this method?

Comment: You should use getCurrentSession instead of opening a new session each time. You can save as many objects you want when you have a session in hand. Heck you can replace all rows of a database if you want.

Comment: For instance, if I try to delete all rows (or update same and delete some) in a method via getSurrentSession(), it does not stop after deleted a few rows (updated some but not deleted some) if any problem arises or connection lost, right? I have to be sure that all changes done in this method.

Comment: Your way of saying the problem is weird, but I can say that you can do multiple operations.

Comment: Yes, I can do but is it guarantee? If some changes done and some changes did not done getCurrentSession() is not safe

Comment: Doesn't work that way, if your method is annotated with Transactional and if something fails, then all operations will be rollbacked. I suggest you read spring and hibernate docs.

Comment: Ok, that is exactly what I need to know. I read many pdf about spring but could not be sure. Then you say I do not need to control roolback, it will automatically performed.

Comment: Yes. There will be automatic rollback and a Exception will also be thrown for you to analyze what went wrong. Don't forget to flush the session after performing database tasks by session.flush();

Comment: flush()? How do I do that? Do I have to put getCurrentSession().flush() in all dao methods for save/update/delete operations? Is not it automatically as well?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, with proper transactional semantics.
`@Transactional` has a property named `rollbackFor = TypeOfException.class`. By default it rolls back `RuntimeException`, but you can specify your own or just `Exception` for any checked exception.

You should have a proper propagation aswell which again you can specify as a property on `@Transactional`. Note that if you set `propagation = REQUIRES_NEW` and an existing transaction calls this method, that will rollback for the nested transaction only. What you're trying to achieve, the most common one I think is to specify `propagation = REQUIRED` - this will not run on its own transaction but proceed on the existing one, which means that on case of failure the whole transaction will rollback.

Comment: I tought using propagation = REQUIRED then I learned that this is already default setting. So I did not added. It seems only I need to do is change openSession() to getCurrentSession() and adding @Transactional is enough. Spring will do the rest.

Comment: Yes, you should use getCurrentSession(), spring will flush at the end aswell.

Comment: Ok Thanks to all. It is very helpfull for me